# How to filter google cloud logs in order to reduce the cost?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, audit-logging

In the IAM console (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/audit) I have activated logging for service Firestore/Datastore API (Data read and Data write).

In the log explorer I can now see a LOT of logs whose method name is "google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Listen" and a few logs with method names "google.firestore.v1.Firestore.ListCollectionIds" and "google.firestore.v1.Firestore.ListDocuments". The later twos are really useful to us, but the former one I don't see any useful information.

The thing is, all those logs are going into a bucket, and we are charge for both the storage and the bandwidth.

So I would like to only receive the useful logs and get rid of the useless ones before they arrive in our bucket.

Answer (score 1):

From the [**`logging export docs`**..[GCP-logging-docs]](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#filter-examples):

> --log-filter : Use this flag to set a filter that matches the log entries you want to include in your sink. If you don't set a filter, all logs from your Cloud project are routed to the destination.

> --exclusion: Use this flag to set an exclusion filter for log entries that you want to exclude from your sink. You can also use the sample function to select a portion of the log entries to exclude. This flag can be repeated; you can create up to 50 exclusion filters per sink.

So you can filter the logs in the sink config using `--log-filter` or `--exclusion`

Comment: Thank you Brian. I am aware I can take logs from the "reception" bucket and put them in a sink, filtering them in the process. However, the unwanted logs would still end up in the reception bucket, and will have to be paid. Thus I'm looking for a solution to be applied earlier in the process. Unless I misunderstood your proposition?

Comment: Yep this was to apply the exclusions early on before they even reach the bucket. This would be configured on the same sink that was used to route logs from audit log to the bucket